# Как дождаться асинхронного ответа вместе с синхронным?

Tags: javascript, angular

Имеется сервис с переменной:  `private this.layers = [];`

Дальше два метода:

```
public loadAsync() {
    .then((res) => this.layers.push(res));
}

public loadSync() {
   this.layers.push({});
}
```

Оба метода вызываются в конструкторе:

```
constructor() {
   this.loadSync();
   this.loadAsync();
}
```

В компоненту инжектирую сервис:

```
constructor(private service: ServiceLoadData) {
     this.layers = [];
}
```

Как дождаться ответа от синхронного и асинхронного вызова, чтобы в компоненте получить результирующий массив `this.layers` из сервиса и отрендерить в шаблоне?

Comment: Никак, constructor не может быть асинхронным. Делайте метод инициализации и делайте его асинхронным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте метод

```
async myMethod() {
    await this.loadAsync();
    this.loadSync();
}
```